# Can't install OS X, shows a message to restart Macbook, repeats

Tags: macos, install, error

I have an installation disk for OS X but when I turn on the Macbook it shows the Apple icon, then goes to a screen of codes and an error message that tells me to restart my Macbook. Once I do, it then repeats and I don't know what to do, any advice?

Comment: which version of osx are you tying to install, what kind of macbook are you using (year, retina?) post a picture of the screen with code, is the osx cd legit?

Comment: its an OCT 2013 13" non retina display macbook, and the disk is legit although it wont eject so i cant see on the disk exactly which OSx it is but i think it was 10.9

Comment: osx 10.9 was never shipped on disks so that could be a problem, which os was installed on the mac before? and can you boot to the recovery drive? (hold alt while booting and several options should pop up)

Comment: it was my mistake the disk is for 10.6.1, if i hold down alt it asked to select network and then nothing else happens, and i do not know what OS was installed before

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is nothing more serious wrong with your computer, you should just be able to use either the recovery partition or internet recovery to install the OS.

You can start the process by holding down Command-R when you restart and the computer should give you the opportunity to download a Mavericks installer. This should happen whether there is a recovery partition available or not. If no recovery partition is available, the computer should use internet recovery.

More information is here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718

Also, it is unlikely that the Mac OS X 10.6.1 disc will work as new Macs will rarely allow old versions of the OS to be installed on them, although seeing a "screen of codes" seems less user-friendly than I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet at this point is taking it to an apple store and asking them to install mavericks for you, since you will need a working mac to download the osx mavericks install files and I assume you don't have another mac?

If you do have another mac you can download mavericks through the app store on that mac an make a usb install drive of the files to install it on your macbook, to do this check [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5856?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)